# Google Analytics on phonegap app

Tags: cordova, google-analytics, cordova-plugins

We are planning to use Google Analytics for tracking in our phonegap based hybrid app. We are using Single Page Architecture based on backbone. It is an existing app and we are planning to add tracking code now.

I know that there are couple of ways to implement it - 1) use the phone gap plugin (https://github.com/danwilson/google-analytics-plugin) 2) use the web version of GTM and add the tracking code to all the pages of the app.

Can someone help me understand the pros and cons of each and which one is the recommended way?

Answer (score 2):

The Cordova Plugins which were developed for Google Analytics most likely piggy back off of the Native iOS & Android Google Analytics SDK's. These are tailored for apps not websites. Might be best to just use the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

the author of https://github.com/appfeel/analytics-google here.

**GTM:**

- P: Easy to go, no need to install
- P: No new learning if you already use it for websites
- C: No native features

**Plugin:**

- P: Native app tracking (specific features for apps in GA pannel)
- P: IDFA & remarketing (with [`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-analytics-adid`](https://github.com/appfeel/analytics-google-adid) see https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2444872)
- P: Offers wrappers for most common actions ([see documentation](https://github.com/appfeel/analytics-google#start-google-analytics)):

  `trackView(screenName, options, success, error);`
- C: Needs to be installed:

  `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-analytics`

In my opinion, if you already know javascript, you'll have no problems into going with plugin option. If you need a fast-to-go solution, you can go to GTM. I'm pretty sure that at some point you'll start to think into switching to plugin option.

Comment: hi.. do you know any corodva plugin for GTM which works well with latest version of GTM?

Comment: If you wish to go for GTM then just include the google analytics script in your index.html, no need for any plugin. If you go for plugin, just install a plugin that uses native features.